# How do I send my output to the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, console

I'm using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.  I would like to capture the output from an error, print it on my console, and so I have in one of my app/service classes

```
rescue => e
  error = e
  msg = "#{e.message}\n"
  e.backtrace.each { |line|
    msg = "#{msg}\n#{line}"
  }
  logger.error msg
  raise e
end
```

but I'm getting the below error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<RunCrawlersService:0x007fd14c2f1e10>
    from /Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/run_mycustom_service.rb:34:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in run_all_crawlers'
    from /Users/nataliab/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/run_mycustom_service.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in run_all_crawlers'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `run_task'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
    from /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
```

How do I properly send my output to the console?

Comment: Though accepted answer solves your problem, you can give a try to [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) for debugging your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`Rails.logger`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger):

```
rescue => e
  Rails.logger.error "#{e.message}\n"
  e.backtrace.each { |line| Rails.logger.error "#{msg}\n#{line}" }
  raise e
end
```

Comment: You can use __any__ logger (e.g. pure Ruby `Logger` or `Log4r::Logger`), Rails logger is just the most popular solution.